# Karma error Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I got a problem when I tried to test my controller. When I run my test I got an error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at assertArg (/Users/tetianachupryna/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1577)
        at assertArgFn (/Users/tetianachupryna/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1588)
        at /Users/tetianachupryna/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8418
        at /Users/tetianachupryna/project/src/spec/controllers/main-controller.spec.js:11
        at /Users/tetianachupryna/project/src/spec/controllers/main-controller.spec.js:17
        at /Users/tetianachupryna/project/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:184
        at http://localhost:9877/karma.js:185
        at http://localhost:9877/context.html:51
```

I know that SO is full of similar questions. But I'm a total null in Angular and JS in general, so those answers didn't help me. From similar questions on SO I discovered that my problem is in wrong definition of the controller but I still can't figure out what I did wrong. I've stack and I'm begging for your help.

First of all here is my *src/app/index.js* file where my module is defined

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngResource',
  'ui.router',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'thing1',
  'thing2']);
```

Here is *src/app/controllers/main-controller.js*

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {
      $scope.state = $state;
      //***
      $scope.isBigStep = function isBigStep() {
        return $state.$current.step == 3;
      };    
  }]);
```

And finally this a file with the test *src/spec/controllers/main-controller.spec.js*

```
describe('MainCtrl', function() {
  var scope, $state, createController;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('MainCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    };
  }));

  it('should make 3 as current step', function() {
    var controller = createController();
    expect(scope.isBigStep()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

In karma config I have all those files

```
files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'src/app/index.js',
      'src/app/controllers/*.js',
      'src/spec/controllers/*.js'
    ],
```

For run my test I use karma-runner plugin in RubyMine.

I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: You are missing you module load. Put `beforeEach(module('myModule'));` before `beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {`?

Comment: Thanks, this trick helped. Could you make a standalone answer that I could accept?

Comment: Sure added an answer. Thx!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are missing is to add the module in the beforeEach hook for test setup. Otherwise the controller will not be found. So add `beforeEach(module('myModule'))`.

```
describe('MainCtrl', function() {
  var scope, $state, createController;

  beforeEach(module('myModule')); //<--- Hook module

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('MainCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    };
  }));

  it('should make 3 as current step', function() {
    var controller = createController();
    expect(scope.isBigStep()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```